# I am trying to Display a Weapon that Inherits a base class of 'Item' and I get an InvalidCastException Error in C#

Tags: c#

The Class Player has i field of List which is the inventory

```
        public List<Item>? Inventory = new List<Item>();
```

And I Have a Derived Class of Weapon

```
public class Weapon : Item
```

I am trying to display the Weapons in the Players Inventory

```
WriteLine("This is what you have in your inventory...");
        WriteLine("\r\nYour Weapons: \r\n");
        foreach (Weapon weapon in Inventory)
        {
            WriteLine($"\r\nWeapon Name: {weapon.Name}\nWeapon Rarity: {weapon.Rarity}\nWeapon Value: {weapon.Value}\nWeapon Damage: {weapon.Damage}\nWeapon Damage Type: {weapon.Damage_Type}");
        }
```

I Thought that It would work as Weapon Is a Derived class of Item
Can Anyone help me please

Comment: what is the exact error message and where it throws ?

Comment: @AliReza it says System.InvalidCastException
  HResult=0x80004002
  Message=Unable to cast object of type 'Wasteland.WeaponMod' to type 'Wasteland.Weapon'.

Comment: Replace Inventory with Inventory.OfType<Weapon>() Not all items in the list are Weapons. OfType<>() filters them

Comment: @EmondErno There is No Function OfType<>

Comment: @AliReza The Error Appears on the foreach(Weapon weapon in Inventory) at the 'Weapon' exactly
I dont know why it brings up `WeaponMod`. Maybe because i am doing `WriteLine("Which Weapon Do you want to Equip this Mod Too.");
            foreach (Weapon item in player.Inventory)`
In the Weapon Mod Class

Comment: `There is No Function OfType` - yes, [there is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=net-5.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should filter your list first

```cs
    foreach (Weapon weapon in inventory.Where(q => q is Weapon) )
    {
        Console.WriteLine(weapon ... 
    }
```

OfType will do the same:

```cs
    foreach (Weapon weapon in inventory.OfType<Weapon>() )
    {
        Console.WriteLine(weapon ... 
    }
```

Comment: I had to put `using System.Linq;`

Comment: I Updated post. I think I should have use OfType first.